# When do CompletableFutures in JDK8 block the execution threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

Example 1:

```
CometableFuture
    .supplyAsync(new MySupplier())
    .someCompletableFutureMethod(new SomeCompletableFutureComsumer())
```

Does the ForkJoin thread ever get blocked?

Example 2:

```
final CompletableFuture cf = new CompletableFuture();
cf = executor.execute(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //do work
        cf.complete(result);
    }
});
cf.whenComplete(new MyConsumer());
```

Do any of the treads involved ever get blocked?

( I know, I should use Callable instead of Runnable :)

Is there any way I can misuse the API without using the method inherited from Future in order to block any thread (main, ForkJoin, executor)?

Assuming I am not using any blocking APIs ( I know future.get() blocks ).

Comment: They block when you perform a blocking operation. What are you asking?

Comment: Assuming I am not using any blocking APIs and I do not call Thread.sleep. It's a debate among the people at work :)))

Comment: You're debating whether threads spontaneously block for no reason? Can you provide some arguments from the "yes they do"-team?

Comment: I also have a hard time understanding the "yes they do" team. I'm playing the Devil's advocate now. I asked the "yes they do" team for an example.

Comment: Advocates have arguments. So far you've presented none.

Comment: Or has the debate really been "They can't get blocked" vs. "Well, they might"?

Comment: Their argument was that CompletableFuture.supplyAsync blocks the same way that future.get() blocks. They said that it does not block the current thread but it blocks the ForkJoin thread so it seems non-blocking but in fact it is. I said that it blocks the ForkJoin only if you use a blocking API. It's the same with callbacks. Their argument was that callbacks never block (NodeJS-style callbacks) while CompletableFutures do. I think they both block only if you use blocking APIs or if you use Future APIs on a CF like cf.get() or cf.get(1000L)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147827/discussion-between-ddreian-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CompletableFuture` adds the `join()` method, which is *kind of* a non-checked exception version of `Future.get()` ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--)).
I don't recommend using it though because, by not taking a timeout, it can hang the thread and you can almost always rewrite the code using `thenApply` and friends.
I try to enforce this by always using `CompletionStage`, which `CompletableFuture` implements.

I don't think any other methods except the ones inherited from `Future` block.

Answer (score 4):

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--) for `get()`:

> Waits if necessary for this future to complete, and then returns its result.

In other words: when you call "blocking" methods on a CompletableFuture, it should block. Otherwise, it will not.

No method in that javadoc has a description that reads: *might randomly block* ;-) !

Answer (score 3):

All those methods will need some form of synchronization, which cannot be implemented properly without ever blocking.

For instance:

1. `supplyAsync()` tries to queue a job in the common `ForkJoin` pool, through its `execute()` method. This method relies on an `Unsafe` and `awaitRunStateLock()` to queue the job;
2. a similar thing applies to your `executor.execute()`, though your implementation might be different;
3. concerning `someCompletableFutureMethod()` (and `whenComplete()`):

   1. except for the `*Async()` methods, it will first need to check whether this future is already completed: if that's the case, the passed-in function will be executed on the calling thread, which you might consider as blocking (though it is actually executing your code);
   2. otherwise, the task must be queued, which relies on loops and an `Unsafe` to do this – see the `CompletableFuture.*push*(*)` methods.
4. `cf.complete()` will need to take care of the child tasks, such as the one sent to `whenComplete()`:

   1. it will need some lock to make sure those tasks are executed only once;
   2. it will execute immediately all the non-asynchronous tasks (like in 3.1);
   3. it will need to schedule the asynchronous tasks (like in 1. and 2.)
5. Most `CompletableFuture` methods that accept a lambda as parameter (and return a new `CompletableFuture`) actually hide a `complete()` call (on the returned future) that will be executed by the same thread that executed the lambda, hence blocking it like in 4.¹

Of course, except in a highly concurrent environment where many threads are trying to push and execute tasks at the same time, you will probably not notice this blocking. Cases 3.1 and 4.2 are the ones you are the most likely to encounter as they occur quite often (if you use the non-`*Async()` methods).

¹ There is a subtle exception with the `thenCompose()` method as the thread that executes the `complete()` call will depend on whether the `CompletionStage` returned by the lambda is already completed or not. Additionally, the non-static `*Async()` methods seem to reuse the executor for this call, so another thread could be used.